# I downloaded a repo with git on PyCharm and many of the indents on almost every single file are off

Tags: windows, pycharm

I'm currently running Python 3.9, PyCharm 2021.1.3 with the Git client bundled, and when I pulled a repo for work, and almost every file has indents that are off, needing both indents and dedents. Has anyone ran into this problem before? I've attached a small screenshot from one of the **init** functions in one of the classes to demonstrate what it is I received when I cloned and downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Git isn't involved in this. Probably what is going on is that you have mixed literal tabs and spaces. Some programs treat a literal tab "as if" it is 4 spaces and some treat it  "as if" it is 8 spaces, and that results in bizarre indentation like the above. The different colors are probably showing you where there are tabs vs spaces, too, although this depends heavily on the IDE/editor. As a general rule, when working with Python, if you can get your IDE/editor to use *only* spaces, you'll at least not have any "how many spaces is a tab" issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the author of the code has mixed spaces and tabs.
You can see `def __init__` at the first line has one level of indentation, probably with a tab.
`self._cp` at line 2 must have two levels of indentation,
probably two spaces each.

If the code runs correctly, all you need to do is reformat the file.
The default keyboard shortcut is:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>